# Where is this die from?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

The die appeared in my old room, lying perfectly on a table, and nobody knows where it came from.

I would be thankful if you would help me identify this die.

[image]

Answer (score 19):

This die is from the [Star Wars: Galactic Battle Game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/75702/star-wars-galactic-battle-game).  This was a game that involved individual action figures being purchased which came with cards & dice for use in the game. Some models like Yoda or Amidala came with black & gold dice, and others like Captain Rex or Ahsoka came with blue & white dice.

[image]

([blue dice source](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/930273/star-wars-galactic-battle-game))

[image]

([gold dice source](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/1567751/star-wars-galactic-battle-game))

Comment: I have tons of these :) Beat me to the answer!